# Are questions related to programming-related qualifications on-topic here?

Tags: discussion, on-topic-definition

As a teen I had no interest in going to university and getting a degree as I did not know what I wanted in life.

I am now a few years in to what I could happily see grow into a life-long career as a software developer (or, at least, a life long career in software development as a whole).

I am looking in to taking a degree level course which offers multiple "specialisations" and I am torn up between the options (namely computer science or software development). I want to ask for other programmers opinions of what they feel are more valuable to the field to help guide me in making an educated decision on what specialisation to take; would such a question be considered on-topic to this site?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why was my question closed or down voted?](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6483/why-was-my-question-closed-or-down-voted)

Answer (score 5):

No, educational and career advice is explicitly off-topic here. It's too localized to your particular needs and situations, tends to attract opinions, and can be too broad. Do feel free to bring such things up [in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/21/the-whiteboard), though.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this topic would be too subjective for Q&A; a course that is of interest and relevance to you will not be so to others.

You would be better served by finding someone with experience of several degree courses in the [Whiteboard chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/21/the-whiteboard); there you can discuss your interests in more detail and get suggestions and recommendations relevant to you.

Be advised that this is very much a personal choice; people may be able to offer hints and suggestions, but they cannot choose your course for you.